# remove "c(" and ")" from string in R - elegant solution?

Tags: r, regex, sqlite

for saving a x,y matrix from R to sqlite, I have to convert it to a list:

```
# convert matrix to list
sql_peaks <- list(peaks)
```

The resulting string looks like

```
"c(123, 234, 235, 3, 5, 6)"
```

The constructor elements c() are disturbing in further data processing steps (and unnecessary), so I remove them with:

```
# remove formatting characters
sql_peaks <- gsub("c(", "", sql_peaks, fixed="TRUE")
sql_peaks <- gsub(")", "", sql_peaks, fixed="TRUE")
```

resulting in:

```
123, 234, 235, 3, 5, 6
```

This works fine, but is there no more elegant solution?

Comment: How does `peaks` look like? Would you present `head(peaks)`? What do you mean by _the resulting string_?

Comment: You could use a single `gsub` function for start: `gsub("c\\(|\\)",'',sql_peaks)`

Comment: Robert, it's considered good etiquette to "accept" an answer that meets all of your needs. Since you've not raised any additional problems, it's safe to assume that it has been resolved. Marking an answer as accepted (checkmark to the left of each answer) not only shows fellow questioners with similar problems that at least one of the answers worked, it also provides a simple "reward" for those who volunteered their time to help you. (If you think the question is since moot and dislike all answers, you can also delete the question, though an oft-debated step.)

Comment: Thanks, r2kvans. I was not aware of that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Two options come to mind using base R:

```
x <- "c(123, 234, c(235), 3, 5, 6)"
```

(I added the `c(234)` in the middle in order to show that the regex only affects the first/last chars in the string.)

```
gsub("^c\\(|\\)$", "", x)
# [1] "123, 234, c(235), 3, 5, 6"
substr(x, 3, nchar(x) - 1)
# [1] "123, 234, c(235), 3, 5, 6"
```

Between the two, as long as you are *certain* that it will always have the leading `c(` and trailing `)`, I'd go with the latter. It is also a little faster:

```
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(a=gsub("^c\\(|\\)$", "", x), b=substr(x, 3, nchar(x) - 1))
# Unit: microseconds
#  expr   min    lq     mean median     uq    max neval
#     a 7.294 7.659 10.20421  8.024 9.4825 46.314   100
#     b 1.459 1.824  2.41480  1.824 2.1890 17.140   100
```

If you are looking for something aesthetic, then this may be your solution.

However, if you are looking for a robust way to store variable and extractable vectors of data from a single database cell, might I suggest using something like JSON?

```
y <- c(123, 234, 235, 3, 5, 6)
jsonlite::toJSON(y)
# [123,234,235,3,5,6] 
jsonlite::fromJSON("[123,234,235,3,5,6]")
# [1] 123 234 235   3   5   6
```

It's robust in that it will handle different types, lengths, etc, rather eloquently. (Also, many DBMS accept `json` and `jsonb` data types.) Frankly, there are other serializing methods out there, JSON just happened to be first on my mind.

Answer (score 2):

or

```
a <- "c(123, 234, 235, 3, 5, 6)"
eval(parse(text = a))
```

Comment: Whenever I see `eval` and databases are concerned, I always think of *SQL injection attacks*. Though it's SQLite, implying a level of network isolation, it still seems unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you mean you want them just as a list of numbers ... you can do this:

```
a <- "c(123, 234, 235, 3, 5, 6)"

values <- regmatches(a, gregexpr("[[:digit:]]+", a))
values <- as.numeric(unlist(values))
```

output:

```
[1] 123 234 235   3   5   6
```

Comment: That is if the result should be a vector of numbers, not a string.